# How can I animate/slide a div into view while moving the contents as opposed to just revealing the contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I would like to use the jquery slideUp and slideDown methods, but instead of the effect being one of the contents merely being revealed, as though a screen is being pulled back and forth, I would like the contents themselves to slide into view, as though a hidden panel is being pulled back and forth.

Comment: *Welcome to StackOverflow!* Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/okgzus7v/ ?

Comment: @abhitalks - Yes, but I don't want the transparency effect also.

Comment: @JonCrowell: Then just remove the opacity and increase the offset. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/okgzus7v/1/

Comment: @JonCrowell: Also, understand that you will have to determine your use-case first, because there are several ways to do it and they all differ depending on need. You can animate `margin`, you can position it `absolute` and animate `top/left` etc.

Comment: @abhitalks - It appears you are just sliding the div offscreen.  I don't have that luxury -- the panel I am sliding back and forth must never appear outside the confines of a containing div.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jononomo/okgzus7v/4/

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/okgzus7v/5/. But, as I said, you have to be very clear on your use-case. Please improve the question by creating a small reproducible example of your layout and use-case. Without which you are not likely to get good answers and the question is liable to be closed sooner or later.

Comment: Okay, thanks much -- you've given me a lot to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery animate check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgLy77us/1/

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var SlideUpAnimate = function(duration, callback){
    var $element = $("#slideUp");
    var startPosition = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + $element.height();
    var finishPosition = $element.position().top;
    $element.css("top", startPosition + "px").show().animate({
        top:  finishPosition + "px"
    },duration, callback);
};

var SlideDownAnimate = function(duration, callback){
    var $element = $("#slideUp");
    var finishPosition = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + $element.height();
    var startPosition = $element.position().top;
    $element.css("top", startPosition + "px").animate({
        top:  finishPosition + "px"
    },duration, function(){
        $element.hide();
        callback();
    });
};

SlideUpAnimate(1000,function(){
    //Some callback code here like:
    SlideDownAnimate(1000);
});
```

});

I think you can adapt to every situation.